# 4 tables sql join

Tags: php, sql

Almost tried 1 hour but can't get it fixed.

I have a database like this.

Category

- catid
- catname

SubCategory

- subcatid
- subcatname
- catid

Tags

- Imgid
- subcatid

Color

- imgid
- color

I have a lot of images lets take image 1 with imgid 1

Category

- catid
  **2**
- catname
  **technology**

SubCategory

- subcatid
  **3**
- subcatname
  **Bicycle**
- catid
  **3**

Tags (we have 2 tags on the img 1)

- Imgid
  **1**
- subcatid
  **3**
- Imgid
  **1**
- subcatid
  **4**
  Color
- imgid
  **1**
- color
  **blue**

So 1 image can have multiple subcategories like Bicycle and Car (a bicycle and a car is on the image) so 2 tags 1 image.

What I want to do now I get all the imgid from Category 2 which have color blue ( I know I can use colorid and add colorname to colorid but lets use colornames to make it a bit easier)

But I only want every imgid 1 time.
So what I want to make is a query like if I am on page Category?id=1?color=blue

I get the catid =1   and color=blue

First I need to get the subcatid's which have catid =1

then I need to get the imgid where tag = sucatid and color = blue

And after that I only want the unique values

So Imgid 1 is returned 1 time.

And on top of that all in php!

I hope some one can help me a bit in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$resultimg = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Category 
            JOIN SubCategory
            ON Category.CatId = SubCategory.CatId
            LEFT JOIN Color
            ON Color.imgid=SubCategory.imgid
            LEFT JOIN Tags
            ON Tags.subcatid=SubCategory.subcatid
            WHERE Color.color = '".$color."' AND Categorie.CatId = ".$CatId);
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or MySQLi instead. Also your example query opens you up to SQL injection attacks. See http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Mm i found out that it only gives the result of the last id so if i have  subcatid 1 subatid 2 both in CatId 1  i only get results of subcatid 2